# How to detect mobile phone and its versions

Tags: php, mobile

How do i detect following mobile phones with php?

1. Symbian
2. List item
3. Android
4. Blackberry  version 5-6
5. Blackberry  version 7
6. Iphone or Ipad

like, if ($mobile='Symbian') {echo "Somthing";}

Comment: Google user agent sniffing. Then google why user agent sniffing is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. Also Google approves of it.

https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/